# Grab particular data from row

Tags: php

I have the following `peoplelist.txt` text file with 2 rows:

> 1,Hello,hello@me.com,Boss
>
> 2,Hello Again,hello2@me.com,Boss

My code to output this is:

```
$handle = fopen("peoplelist.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo $line;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Is it possibly instead of outputting the entire line, I just output the data in the 2nd column (aka `Hello` & `Hello Again`)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$handle = fopen("/temp/peoplelist.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

        $parts = explode(',',$line);

        echo $parts[1] . PHP_EOL;

    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: That worked beautifully, many thanks, Dave! Will explore `explode` now :-)

Answer (score 3):

Since that's CSV data:

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
    echo $line[1];
}
```