# Find string in a text file with PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a file called `peoplelist.txt` which has the following text:
`1,mikey.mcgurk,1,boss.man`

However, when I try to use the `$name` later on in my script when searching a second file, it doesn't work :(

The contents of `people.txt` is just `mikey.mcgurk`

So the following works great **BUT** if I use `$searchfor = $name`, it fails. Why?

```
$handle = fopen("peoplelist.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $parts = explode(',',$line);
        $name = $parts[1] . PHP_EOL;
        $name = strtolower($name);
        $name = str_replace(' ', '.', $name);
        $boss = $parts[3] . PHP_EOL;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

echo $name; // this echoes out 'mikey.mcgurk', as expected

$file = 'people.txt';
$searchfor = 'mikey.mcgurk';

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

**NOTE:** This isn't 2 separate scripts, it's all one PHP file - I've just split it for this question :-)

Comment: But $name is not set in the second example. This seems like a xy problem. Explain what you want instead.

Comment: Apologies, that is all one script. It maybe isn't clear, will amend :)

Comment: Not really much clearer now. What are you ttying to do? What is in people.txt?

Comment: Third line down, people.txt contents = `mikey.mcgurk` I'm trying to search `people.txt` for the value stored in `$name` :)

Comment: Several things make me think this won't work, but get rid of the `PHP_EOL` in your strings.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I do find it odd that echo-ing out `$name` shows `mikey.mcgurk` however, I can't use it later in the same script :-(

Comment: Also, you're trying to replace a space with a dot but you show a dot in the file.  Seems backwards.

Comment: Because you are adding a newline character to it with `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: try changing `$name = $parts[1] . PHP_EOL;` to `$name = $parts[1];`

Comment: Finally, some progress hehee. Thank you, @spielerds :-) This now works perfectly. Please add as an answer :-D

Comment: You're welcome, byt @AbraCadaver said it before me :)

Comment: Also, I don't see how the pattern works because you escape the `$` which means its looking for the literal character.

Comment: Aside: you may want to look at Php's *csv functions.

Comment: @Progrock: Yes, same OP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842435/grab-particular-data-from-row

Comment: Seems there is bosses everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the regex pattern. But since there is some other things that can be done better I add that too.

```
$list = file_get_contents("peoplelist.txt");
list($something, $name, $somethingelse, $boss) = explode(',',$line);
$name = str_replace(' ', '.', strtolower($name));

echo $name; 

$file = 'people.txt';
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = "/" . $name . "/m"; 

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
    echo "Found matches:\n";
    echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
    echo "No matches found";
}
```

Your regex didnt make sense. You wanted it to start with anything.
Then why force start with? And off course the literal $.